# C# scanning of file attributes

Tags: c#

```
    private void Scan_files_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            string filePath = Convert.ToString(listView1.Items[i]);
           // MessageBox.Show("Files found: " + filePath, "Message");
           // FileAttributes fileAttributes = File.GetAttributes(filePath);
            if (((File.GetAttributes(filePath) & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly) && ((File.GetAttributes(filePath) & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden) && ((File.GetAttributes(filePath) & FileAttributes.System) == FileAttributes.System))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File's Attributes: " + File.GetAttributes(filePath));
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show(" NO matching attrbutes");
        }
    }
```

I cannot get this working :S

Comment: It would also help to know exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this piece of code to see the File Attributes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    string filePath = Convert.ToString(listView1.Items[i]);

    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        return;
    //make sure you have a correct file path in filePath variable

    // check whether a file is read only
    bool isReadOnly = ((File.GetAttributes(filePath) & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly);

    // check whether a file is hidden
    bool isHidden = ((File.GetAttributes(filePath) & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden);

    // check whether a file is system file
    bool isSystem = ((File.GetAttributes(filePath) & FileAttributes.System) == FileAttributes.System);

    if (isReadOnly || isHidden || isSystem)
        MessageBox.Show("File's Attributes: " + File.GetAttributes(filePath));
    else
        MessageBox.Show("No. matching attrbutes");
}
```

Reference: [File Attributes [C#]](http://www.csharp-examples.net/file-attributes/)

Happy Coding...

Answer (score 0):

Investigate what `filePath` you are actually getting, you can use a breakpoint, or before you call File.GetAttributes, try:

```
if (!File.Exists(filePath))
{
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("File {0} not found.", filePath));
}
```